# Trying to get property of non-object in line 18

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, mysqlconnector

En la línea que hay error es en esta :

```
if ($resultado->num_rows() > 0) ...
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
    $mysqli= new mysqli('localhost','id5840508_root','******','id5840508_hospital
');

    $salida="";
    $query="SELECT*FROM paciente ORDER By id";

    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
        $query="SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE codigo_pac LIKE '%".$q."%' OR  apellido_paterno LIKE '%".$q."%' OR  apellido_materno LIKE '%".$q."%' 
                    OR  nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'" ;

    }

    $resultado= $mysqli->query($query);



            if ($resultado->num_rows() > 0) {
        $salida.=" <table class='tabla_datospac'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nº</td>
                        <td>  CÓDIGO </td>
                        <td>APELLIDO PATERNO</td>
                        <td>APELLIDO MATERNO</td>
                        <td>NOMBRE</td>
                        <td>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</td>
                        <td>SEXO</td>
                        <td>ZONA</td>
                        <td>CALLE</td>
                        <td>Nº DOM.</td>
                        <td>LOCALIDAD</td>
                        <td>SALARIO MENSUAL</td>
                        <td>OCUPACION ACTUAL</td>
                        <td>FECHA / INGRESO</td>



                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";   

                while ($fila= $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $salida.="  <tr>
                                <td >".$fila['id']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['codigo_pac']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['apellido_paterno']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['apellido_materno']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['fecha_nac']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['sexo']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['zona']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['calle']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['nro']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['localidad']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['salario_mensual']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['ocupacion_actual']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['fecha_ingreso_a_trabajo']."</td>



                            </tr>";
                }

                $salida.="</tbody></table>";

                } 
                else
                {
                $salida.="<H4>NO EXISTE</h4>";
                }

                echo $salida;
                $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: Tu query tiene un error de sintaxis lo que hace que `$resultado` no sea un objeto válido al cual poder aplicarle `num_rows()`
... Corrigela: `$query="SELECT * FROM paciente ORDER By id";` prueba de nuevo y comenta si sigue el mismo error.

Comment: ahorita edite por error que en    num_rows()   es solo num_rows  ... pero me sale este error Trying to get property of non-object in /storage/ssd5/508/5840508/public_html/App/buscar.php on line 18...... y es en :    if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {

Comment: Al parecer no entendiste mi comentario anterior. ¿No te fijas que tu variable `$query` tiene la consulta **mal escrita:**?  `SELECT*FROM paciente ORDER By id` esa consulta no funcionará nunca porque tienes escrito **todo junto `SELECTASTERISCOFROM`**, por lo tanto `$result` no será nunca un conjunto de resultados válido, sino que será `FALSE`. El error eso es lo que dice, como `$result` es `FALSE`, no le puedes aplicar la propiedad `num_rows`.

Comment: Corregí eso y sigue saliendo lo mismo :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba el código así. Es lo que yo llamo un *código de flujo controlado*.

Puede que haya un error en tu segunda consulta.

Aquí, ocurra lo que ocurra, el código te dirá exactamente el error que está ocurriendo, ya que no se da nada por supuesto: **todas las variables son evaluadas**.

```
<?php
$mysqli= new mysqli('localhost','id5840508_root','******','id5840508_hospital
');

if ($mysqli){
    $query="SELECT * FROM paciente ORDER By id";

    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);

        /*
           *OJO: Esta consulta es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL
           *cuando en una consulta intervienen datos externos
           *como la variable $q aquí utilizada
           *la práctica recomendada es el uso de consultas preparadas
        */
        $query="SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE codigo_pac LIKE '%".$q."%' OR  apellido_paterno LIKE '%".$q."%' OR  apellido_materno LIKE '%".$q."%'
                    OR  nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'" ;

    }
    $resultado= $mysqli->query($query);

    if($resultado){

        if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {

            /*
                *OJO AQUÍ: para ser coherentes, declaramos $salida
                *como una VARIABLE NUEVA en esta 1ª línea de esta parte
                *De hecho, $salida se declara como tal en cada parte del flujo
            */

            $salida=" <table class='tabla_datospac'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nº</td>
                        <td>  CÓDIGO </td>
                        <td>APELLIDO PATERNO</td>
                        <td>APELLIDO MATERNO</td>
                        <td>NOMBRE</td>
                        <td>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</td>
                        <td>SEXO</td>
                        <td>ZONA</td>
                        <td>CALLE</td>
                        <td>Nº DOM.</td>
                        <td>LOCALIDAD</td>
                        <td>SALARIO MENSUAL</td>
                        <td>OCUPACION ACTUAL</td>
                        <td>FECHA / INGRESO</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";

            while ($fila= $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $salida.="  <tr>
                                <td >".$fila['id']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['codigo_pac']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['apellido_paterno']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['apellido_materno']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['fecha_nac']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['sexo']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['zona']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['calle']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['nro']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['localidad']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['salario_mensual']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['ocupacion_actual']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['fecha_ingreso_a_trabajo']."</td>
                            </tr>";
            }

            $salida.="</tbody></table>";
        }
        else
        {
            $salida.="<H4>NO EXISTE</h4>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $salida="Error en la consulta: ".$mysqli->error;
    }

    $mysqli->close();

}
else
{
    $salida="Error de conexión a la base de datos";

}
echo $salida;

?>
```

Comment: A. Cedano... estuve. gran tiempito con este error... pero lo pude solucionar... gracias a esta opción que me diste... Agradezco en verdad tu ayuda y orientación.

Comment: Me alegro @KVN20, de todos modos, quiero decirte que tu código no es seguro, no al menos en la query que pasas con los valores de `$q` concatenados, ya que un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular los valores para hacer daño en tu sistema o en tus datos. Pero ese es otro tema. Cuando puedas, lee sobre Inyección SQL, aquí mismo hay buenas preguntas respuestas sobre el tema. Si la respuesta te sirvió como solución puedes activar la flecha a la izquierda de la misma para indicar que el problema fue resuelto gracias a esta respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Es un error de paradigma, estas trabajando con el driver mysqli y tratando de usar estilo orientado a objetos; por lo tanto la siguiente línea

```
if ($resultado->num_rows() > 0) {
```

Debería quedar del modo siguiente

```
if ($fila = $resultado->num_rows > 0) {
```

Para mayor referencia te dejo la [documentación oficial](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) para que corrobores

Te comento también que tienes mal la siguiente línea

```
$query="SELECT*FROM paciente ORDER By id";
```

Esta mal escrita debería ser así

```
$query="SELECT * FROM paciente ORDER BY id";
```

> No escribas la query toda junta o no la sabrá interpretar

Comment: Hola Alfredo... cambie ese parametro y pues sigo con el mismo error  :      Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: te actualice mi respuesta @KVN20

Comment: Gracia Alfredo, corregí eso pero aún sigo con el mismo error en esa línea de código... con lo corroborado parece ser otra la falla :S